# Id of option tag's are same, so whenever I set my option tag value bydefault it will set first tag value and stop there, so how to solve this?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
   <body>
    <table id="tableTag">
     <tr>
      <td>System</td>
      <td>
       <select name="">
        <option value="1" id="1">1</option>
        <option value="2" id="2">2</option>
        <option value="3" id="3">3</option>
       </select>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Strategy</td>
     <td>
      <select name="">
        <option value="1" id="1">1</option>
        <option value="2" id="2">2</option>
        <option value="3" id="3">3</option>
      </select>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>

  <script>
   let defaultValue = 2;
   let arr = [];
   let getValue = document.querySelectorAll('option');
   for(let i = 0; i<getValue.length; i++){
     arr.push(getValue[i].id);
   }
   for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
     const element = arr[j];
     if(defaultValue == element){
     let optionId = document.getElementById(element);
     optionId.selected = true;
   }
  }
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am begginer in javascript
Kindly help me to find better solution.
Id of option tags are same, so whenever I set my option-tag value by default it will set first tag value and stop there, so how to solve this?

Comment: id is unique,cant be same.instead of that you can use class.that's why every time it is taking first element by that id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select the option and set the `selected` attribute you do not need to assign `id` attributes, You can simply loop through the nodelist and assign the attribute if the node matches. Alternatively you can use a more complex expression in `querySelector` to target the specific option.

As others have noted - IDs **must** be unique to be valid.

```js
let defaultValue = 2;
let arr = [];

document.querySelectorAll('option').forEach(opt=>{
  arr.push(opt.value); // this is not really required
  if( opt.value==defaultValue )opt.selected=true;
});


// OR...
document.querySelector('select[name="strategy"] option[value="2"]').selected=true
```

```html
<table id='tableTag'>
 <tr>
  <td>System</td>
  <td>
   <select name='system'>
    <option value='1'>1
    <option value='2'>2
    <option value='3'>3
   </select>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Strategy</td>
 <td>
  <select name='strategy'>
    <option value='1'>1
    <option value='2'>2
    <option value='3'>3
  </select>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

id is unique,cant be same.instead of that you can use class.that's why every time it is taking first element by that id

Answer (score 0):

IDs need to be unique on a page. Multiple elements cannot have the same id.
JavaScript will have a problem while fetching elements when there are multiple elements with the same id and will usually fetch the first one.
To avoid this go for different ids for different elements on the page.